# YouTube iframe API http / https protocols and origin issues

Tags: iframe, https, youtube, safari, youtube-iframe-api

I'm getting various http/https and origin errors with the YouTube iframe API that are only an issue with Safari (i think on most versions, I'm using version 7.0.4)

I'm getting these errors:

> Unable to post message to https://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://example.com.

and:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://example.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

The result is that the video remains black and sometimes has a play icon within it. Often the video will load, its fairly random. The videos themselves are automatically played so never need to be clicked. All other browsers behave fine.

The origin parameter is being set like so when creating the YTPlayer:

```
playerVars: {
    origin: 'http://example.com'
}
```

YouTube itself is being loaded like this:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

I've tried specifying "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; I get the same errors. my domain is http not https - this i'm guessing is the root of the problem here, i'm not sure how to stop youtube defaulting to https.